# Review Queues: What to do if question is for Magento 1 and user answer for Magento2

Tags: discussion

Recently, I have a First post for review and I found that [Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122017/updating-custom-variable-value-programatically) was asked for `Magento 1` and user-posted late [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318583/68003) to the question which related to `Magento 2`.

What to do in such a case? Should I use `flag` or `No action needed`?

> **Question**: [updating custom variable value programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122017/updating-custom-variable-value-programatically)

> **Answer**: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318583/68003

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Bhaumik as person has added if you want for M2 you can use this way, I think answer is not right but it add some value to post

so in my opinion let it be there so `No action needed`